# Use of present perfect tense in news articles

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, simple-past

When to use present perfect tense has always been confusing for me.
I know that it carries a sense of continuity from the past, but many times in news articles, I come across sentences with present perfect tense that do not have anything to do with continuity.

For example,
"President Trump has promised legal action in the coming days as he refused to ..."
Here, it does not sound right to say that Trump had been continuously promising legal action.

Another example:
"While the mission is “indeed challenging,” McDowell said China has already landed twice on the moon...."

For this one, China landing on the moon twice was events completed in the past. They are not landing continuously.. So why use present perfect tense here rather than just go "China already landed twice on the moon"?

What nuance does present perfect tense carry that I'm not getting here?
I would greatly appreciate any help!
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Not so much 'continuity from the past' as 'significance to the present'. The President's promise of legal action still stands. The Chinese have landed on the moon, showing that they are still capable of doing so.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/445327/349876
 i  I have rented a car ever since.                                                        [continuative]
  ii  I have rented a car before.                                                           [experiential/existential]
  iii  I have rented a car, so I will be able to travel easily.                             [resultative]
  iv  I have just rented a car.                                                             [recent past]

Comment: One of the [four senses of the present perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69335/15299) is its _Hot News!_ sense, widely used in newspapers and headlines.

Comment: What @JohnLawler said. *I **have seen** the light!* sounds far more "immediately relevant / arresting" than *I **saw** the light!*

Comment: Note the relevance of ***already*** here. *They did it* is [much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did+it%2Chave+done+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdid%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20done%20it%3B%2Cc0) than *They have done it*, but [that "skew" reverses](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=already+did+it%2Chave+already+done+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calready%20did%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20already%20done%20it%3B%2Cc0) with *They have **already** done it.*

Comment: Yes, _already_ has a time vector parallel to that of the perfect construction, so they're often found together.